# cannot find zipfile directory in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, unzip, python-zipfile

I uploaded my zip file completely and then ran the following command:

```
!unzip -qq Train.zip
```

I get this error:

```
[Train.zip]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of Train.zip or
        Train.zip.zip, and cannot find Train.zip.ZIP, period.
```

I restarted the runtime and also reuploaded the zip file. That didn't help.

Comment: The zip file is corrupted, or it's not a zip file to begin with.